# Properly install flutter including android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

So I wanted to do some hobby-app-developement and therefore I wanted to start with flutte. I found this YouTube-Series (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ukSR1GRtMU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ) which tries to explain step by step how to start. Problem is I am failing on the installation.

What I did:

1. I downloaded Git 2.34.1 for Windows, Android Studio 2020.3.1 for Windows and flutter_windows_2.8.1-stable.zip
2. I then ran Git and Android Studio, but did not start Android Studio
3. I then ran Flutter
4. after installation i ran "flutter_console.bat" and typed the command "flutter doctor" as mentioned in the video:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1466], locale de-DE)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.
```

5. I thought Android Studio was just in wrong directory, so I typed "flutter config --android-sdk C:\ProgramFiles\Android\AndroidStudio\bin\studio64.exe" (thats where android studio sits as), but still it couldn't be found by flutter
6. I tried to ran android studios afterwars just to find out, that it still had to install some shit, I then did

So I think the problem could be on multiple sides. Either Android Studio or Flutter isn't properly installed. I messed with the directory for Android Studio before it was installed properly and that messed with flutter, now he doesn't know where to find android studio

Or it is somewhere else. Does anybody knows how to solve this? I am sorry, I am very bad at installation and hope you get my problem in the first place. If something isn't clear, plese ask the questions and even better say where I have to look to find the answers. Appreciate y'all

PS: another option would be to uninstall those 3 programs, but I'm scared some bulk is gonna stay on the drive and messes with future installation

**>Update:**
I did follow the link from Jino Prince and it solved my problem to not locate sdk. However now it seems like something isn't up to date. Following statement occured:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
```

So I did run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest" but it doesn't seem to do something, at least the problem stayed the same. I did try to understand it on the stated link, but i just don't.
Also i have to agree to license, but i can't because of the first error, but that should work as soon as the first is fixed

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem. If anyone is going to face the same problem it might help, so I'm gonna post what helped me.

First problem was that Flutter couldn't "see" Android Studio. So what I needed to do was give him the right android sdk file track. Following video helped me out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GuGlATHYX8
Also I added all the enviromental variables mentioned in the video, though I don't know if it was necessary.

Next problem was a missing tool: cmdline-tools
For that the following website showed how to install it (should be possible to install different tools the same way)
https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/202/cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-error-flutter/

After that all I had to do is to accept the licenses, but flutter itself says how to do so (copy the command, press enter, and accept all licenses with "y", after carefully reading it )

I hope it might help somebody else